# Previous deleted text keyboard shortcuts keep appearing

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I kept a bunch of keyboard shortcuts via System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts and over time, I deleted some shortcuts that are not necessary for me and added new ones.

Some time ago, it appears that the unwanted shortcuts appeared back when the added one didn’t appear — manually deleting them in the system panel only made them return.

How do I keep *one* set of keyboard shortcuts please?

Comment: Do you have any other Apple devices?

Comment: Yes, I do. Another iMac @ work. Same thing happened on that. With the same iCloud details as this one.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts sync over iCloud. Next time you delete one, delete it from all of your devices.

Comment: This is a similar topic on AskDifferent: [How to permanently delete text substitutions?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182546/how-to-permanently-delete-text-substitutions)
And an Apple Discussion Here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/27060388

Answer (score 1):

Deleting from all devices does not appear to permanently fix the problem.  They live in the cloud somewhere, and I was told by Apple in 7/15 that the are working on a permanent fix.  Mine stay away from the most part, but have come back occasionally on my MacBook and iPad.